# PHP says "No Database selected" even after using mysqli_select_db()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a simple code to fetch 2 elements from a table in my database called Plasma.
It seems the connection is being made well but I am unable to select any database due to unknown reason.

Code :

```
<?php
$db  = "Plasma"; 
$dbH = "localhost";
$dbU = "plasma";
$dbP = "plasma";
      $dbCon = mysqli_connect($dbH,$dbU,$dbP,$db);
        if(!dbCon){
            echo "Conenction Fail";
        }
        mysqli_select_db($dbCon,$db);
        $qry = "select Mid,Mname from ya_movies order by DOA limit 5;";
        $Response = mysqli_query($dbCon,$qry);
        echo mysqli_error($dbCon);                     ?>
```

The Output is

```
No database selected
```

Comment: You don't select any database in your code, what happens when you do?

Comment: your db is capitalized unlike other credentials

Comment: @Havsmonstret they do

Comment: The character-case matters! Maybe your database is named `plasma` which you are referring to as `Plasma`

Comment: @Your Common Sense Hmm yeah, didn't read that all thoroughly. What happens when you use mysqli_select_db instead of specifying it in mysqli_connect?

Comment: i used mysqli_select_db, sorry that i missed it when i copy pasted the code.

Comment: try using `USE plasma;` as your first query

Comment: @BMC such a "miss" *is* a reason for whatever errors you have.

Comment: What happens when you `select Mid,Mname from Plasma.ya_movies`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense , No the code does contain a mysqli_select_db() which I have updated here. sorry for the confusion. But am still having the issue.

Comment: **Whatever** errors it is. A general inattentiveness.

Comment: My previous comment was of no help?

Comment: @Stephan having the same error even after using "USE Plasma"

Comment: Hi @BMC, sorry for seemingly being grumpy and a bit off topic, but (in the spirit of being positively helpful) for the benefit of anyone who has to read your code, I suggest you just use variables $dbHostname and $query - missing out arbitrary characters from strings makes them hard to predict and leads to mistakes (especially in PHP). Also I'd be consistent about the use of case for variable names - either camelCase [recommended for PHP] or PascalCase but not both.

Comment: @amulous , No the DB name is "Plasma". Just checked.

Comment: what does mysqli_error say after running "USE Plasma" query?

Comment: Yet another long and windy topic spawned by a silly typo... I wish I will learn to spend my life in a more profitable way

Comment: @YourCommonSense " Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'Plasma'"

Comment: Go on check your credentials first then, and if your variables contain the right values. You don't need no Stack Overflow help for this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense checking with 'root' user. It's strange that it says "for user ''@'localhost' to" -> the user name is missing

Answer (score 11):

It's a typical case of not enough debug information:

```
mysqli_select_db($dbCon, $db);
```

You don't check for the return value; it may return `false` to indicate it couldn't change the database (probably due to permissions). I would suggest putting this in place and run it:

```
if (!mysqli_select_db($dbCon, $db)) {
    die("Uh oh, couldn't select database $db");
}
```

If this happens, double check the name, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, I dont have the reputation yet, but:

```
if(!$dbCon){
    echo "Connection Failure!";
}
```

try this:

```
if (!$dbCon) {
    die('Connection Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Might give a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, but it makes no difference because `dbCon` will evaluate to `"dbCon"` making the condition superfluous.

Comment: Tried both with $ and without.

Answer (score 1):

> PHP says “No Database selected” even after using mysqli_select_db()

**Nope, it doesn't**, if you are using valid credentials.

PHP will set current database all right either way.
The only reason for not to do so is a *some sort of typo you made.*

You just need to be sure that you *actually called this function* with *proper database name.*
And then double-check it.
Of course a user have to have rights to access that database.

That's all.
There is no magic.
There is no bug in mysqli.
There is but only one rational explanation. Always trust to your common sense.

A couple of rules you need to learn to avoid such a problem in a future:

1. In all your further codes ALWAYS make `error_reporting(E_ALL);` the very first line and **never** turn it off nor make it less. This way you will be notified of the errors occurred in your code.
2. Before using database credentials in the code, test them in a console. This way you will make sure that your credentials are proper and works. If have problem with setting proper credentials - as k a question on setting them.
3. If there are no errors and credentials are all proper - check for the typos in the code.

Comment: That's not the only possible reason. It could very well be a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!dbCon){
   echo "Conenction Fail"; 
}
```

You forgot to add $ in dbCon variable.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I created a new database but it could not be selected from PHP. Yet the test database could be selected. I solved it by changing the $user to 'root'. For your case :

```
$dbU = 'root'
```

That should work for you.

Comment: This may solve the problem. But a better solution would be to configure the database so it worked with the user specified.